# Random Not Defined for discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to code a Discord bot and make an 8ball, but it tells me random isn't defined.

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
        responses = [ "It is certain.",
                    "It is decidedly so.",
                    "Without a doubt.",
                    "Yes - definitely.",
                    "You may rely on it.",
                    "As I see it, yes.",
                    "Most likely.",
                    "Outlook good.",
                    "Yes.",
                    "Signs point to yes.",
                    "Reply hazy, try again.",
                    "Ask again later.",
                    "Better not tell you now.",
                    "Cannot predict now.",
                    "Concentrate and ask again.",
                    "Don't count on it.",
                    "My reply is no.",
                    "My sources say no.",
                    "Outlook not so good.",
                    "Very doubtful."]
        await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choices(responses)}')
```

And I'm getting the error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Is there something wrong in my code? This is my first time coding.

Comment: Have you done `import random` anywhere previously in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to `import random`
Go to the top of your code where you `import discord` and enter down and `import random` then try
Refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you have a variable called `random`.  I see it is supposed to have a function called `choices`.  You use it in the line in your f-string:

```
await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choices(responses)}')
```

Make sure you defined it prior to this line.

Or, if this is the standard `random` in Python core, then like [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) suggests, make sure you imported it.